# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters in

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to run an update query through php to a postgresql database. When i try to do that i get an error.

I tried changing the `id = ?` to `id = :id` but it didn't work

My `update` function:

```
//update a student
    public function updateStudent(){
      $query = 'UPDATE ' . $this->table . ' ( name, course) VALUES ( :name, :course) WHERE id = ? ;';
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

      $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));
      $this->name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
      $this->course = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->course));
      $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
      $stmt->bindParam(':course', $this->course);

      if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
      }
      //print error
      printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
      return false;
    }
```

The error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters in...`

It says the error is on line 58 which is the line that reads:
`$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);`
I the error is within the line above 58.

Update:
If i use `id = :id` instead of `id = ?`, i get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1: UPDATE students ( name, course) VALUES ( $1, $2) WHERE id = ... ^ in`

Comment: Okay what error do you get when you do use :id and not mixing named and positional param? Please update your question accordingly. Also, is that actually valid PostgreSQL UPDATE syntax?

Comment: `( :name, :course) WHERE id = ?` this won't work

Comment: i updated it, you can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use :param and ?  use :id instead of ?

but for update you could use

```
    'UPDATE ' . $this->table . ' 
        set  name = :name, 
         course = :course 
      WHERE id = :id ;';




   public function updateStudent(){
      $query = 'UPDATE ' . $this->table . ' 
                  set  name = :name, 
                       course = :course 
                WHERE id = :id ;';
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

      $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));
      $this->name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
      $this->course = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->course));
      $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
      $stmt->bindParam(':course', $this->course);

      if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
      }
      //print error
      printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, you're a life saver. It worked. I'm still a noob with postgresql commands, so im still struggling a bit. But thanks